# visual foxpro 9.0, how to find/get repeated records

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbf

I have a table with 2001233 records.
I can use 'Select distinct * from that_table' to get all records not repeated.
Maybe about 2001100 records.

How to get those 133 records into another table if I want to check the records disappeared after 'distinct'.

Another question is
When appending new records from one table to another table, how to check that the appended record is not already in the target table?

thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be a hack and slow for 2+ million rows but you can do this:

```
Select Sys(2017,'',0,3) As crc, * ;
    from myTable Into Cursor crsTemp ;
    nofilter

Select * From crsTemp ;
    where crc In ;
    ( Select crc From crsTemp;
    having Count(*) > 1 ;
    group By crc) ;
    into Cursor crsDupes ;
    nofilter

Select crsDupes
Browse
```

You should have used primary key from the start.

For your second question, I think it is best to use "insert into" rather than append. i.e.:

```
Insert into tableA ;
  select * from tableB t1 ;
  where not exists ( ;
      select * from tableA t2 ;
      where t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, quite useful.Solution 1 is good but contains the "first-occur" records so the number of the records is more than 133.I am trying to modify the code.I want to get the result that looks like doing difference between two tables (origin one and distinct one). :)

Comment: Yes naturally it would be more than 133. As I already said, you should have primary key from the start. In case of duplication, what does it matter which one is the duplicate? After all, a duplicate is a duplicate, it doesn't have an order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to find the duplicate records:
Assuming that you don't keep deleted records hanging around...

```
select tableA
set deleted off
delete all
index on <key expression> to keyfield unique
set deleted on
recall all
browse for deleted
```

This process will delete all the records, and the recall statement will only apply to the indexed records, leaving the duplicates tagged as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if there is a duplicate record.

```
SELECT colName, count(*) FROM tblName GROUP BY colName HAVING count(*) > 1
```